# Show that this matrix product is bounded

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, normed-spaces

Suppose  we have a symmetric real matrix $\pmb M$ satisfying:

$$\underset{\pmb\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^p:||\alpha||=1}{\min}\;\pmb \alpha\pmb M\pmb \alpha^{\top}\geqslant k>0.$$

Then, I am trying to show that the norm:

$$\underset{\pmb z\in\mathbb{R}^p}{\max}\;\left|\left|\left(\pmb M+\pmb z^{}\pmb z^{\top}\right)^{-1}\pmb z^{\top}\right|\right|^2\leqslant\; ?$$

is bounded. I can see how intuitively that would be true, but I fail to build a connection between (the inverse of) $k$ and an upper bound for the second expression.

Comment: Should the last $z^\top$ be a $z$ inside your norm?

Comment: yes (it should be inside the norm.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Sherman–Morrison–Woodbury formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) we arrive at
$$(M + zz^\top)^{-1} z = \frac{M^{-1} z}{1+z^\top M^{-1} z}.$$
From here it is easy to conclude by using
$$z^\top M^{-1} M^{-1}z \le \|M^{-1}\| z^\top M^{-1} z.$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what you mean by $||M||$ when $M$ is a matrix?

Comment: The induced operator norm, i.e., $\sup_{\|x\|\le1}\|Mx\|$.

Comment: Are you sure it is not $z^{\top}M^{-1}z$ in the denominator (first equality)?

Comment: Oh yes, the inverse was missing!